# Docker with flow require hook doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, docker, requirejs, flowtype, commonjs

Well I'm trying to fix a docker which stopped working at some point after updating. When testing I notice the following error (exempt of console)

```
/njs # npm install flow-remove-types
+ flow-remove-types@1.2.3
added 12 packages from 23 contributors and audited 4202 packages in 5.862s
found 114 vulnerabilities (58 low, 52 moderate, 2 high, 2 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
/njs # node app.js
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'flow-remove-types/register'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/njs/app.js:30:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

The corresponding line/code in `app.js` is:

```
require('flow-remove-types/register');
```

(As per [explanation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flow-remove-types#use-the-require-hook))

As you can see I very explicitly try to install flow-remove-types. However when I start node the library isn't found (`node app.js`).

How can this occur? 
I'm running this inside an (official) node v8.15.1 alpine docker.